# Add post quality to data dump & SEDE

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer

I think it would be quite interesting to add post quality to the data dump, to check for correlations with other things (like tag, for example).

However, I'm not sure where it should go (in Post, or PostHistory?), nor whether this is currently stocked in the database, or calculated on the fly.

Comment: What do you mean by "post quality"?

Comment: @Pekka: http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts, `$('.quality-score');`

Comment: ah, thanks. Wasn't aware that info was publicly available

Comment: the trouble is we do not store it yet in Posts, so we would have to recalc it when dumping, I think it is a reasonable request though

Comment: @waffles, and it would/could change with time (that's why I mentioned PostHistory). @badp said maybe alternatively you could release the algorithm, but I'm guessing that might count as secret sauce?

Comment: I hypothesize that among posts marked as low quality, high reputation users are overrepresented.  I'd really like to be able to use SEDE to investigate this further.  This request hasn't been accepted or declined, but it just had its first birthday.  Is that a bad sign?  ED:  I'm not implying anything about the actual content or correctness of the posts, I just want to see what if any other correlations there are.  Maybe low quality answers are routinely provided to a specific kind of question?